# Getting error of Unterminated character class in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[/: Unterminated character classUncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[/: Unterminated character class

```
 // Searching in ListBox
    $('#Search').keyup(function () {
        var valThis = $(this).val().toUpperCase();

        $('#lstDCU > option').each(function () {
            var itemText = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
            ((itemText.search(valThis) != -1) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide());
        });
    });
```

Comment: I don't think it is from this code... if it is then there are some invisible characters in your source file

Comment: I am getting error on  ((itemText.search(valThis) != -1) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide()); It throws error only for special character like $,[,^ etc

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1b1908gd/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is a runtime error.

The [search()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search) method expects a regex as its parameter, but if you are passing a string it should be escaped for regex special characters like `^, |` etc so

```
if (!RegExp.escape) {
    RegExp.escape = function (value) {
        return value.replace(/[\-\[\]{}()*+?.,\\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
    };
}

$('#Search').keyup(function () {
    var valThis = RegExp.escape($(this).val().toUpperCase());

    $('#lstDCU > option').each(function () {
        var itemText = $(this).text().toUpperCase();
        ((itemText.search(valThis) != -1) ? $(this).show() : $(this).hide());
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/1b1908gd/)